# Prove an addition property of Natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, peano-axioms

> Prove: For any $x,y \in \mathbb{N}, y \neq x+y$.

I'm only suppose to use the Peano axioms as defined here http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/numbers/peano.pdf and the properties of addition in $\mathbb{N}$.

I've already proved most of the properties of addition excepting this one and I don't know how to approach to this.

Comment: Prove by induction.

Comment: @user143201 Do you need further help with this?

Comment: I did solved it with your hint. But I don't know if I have to click the answer button, because what you gave me was only a hint

Comment: @user143201 It is acceptable to not do anything, to accept my answer even though is was only a hint and also to just type your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:** Take an arbitrary $x\in \mathbb N$ and prove the statement $\forall y\in \mathbb N(x\neq x+y)$ by induction. You'll have to use the definition of $+$, the injectivity of the successor function and the fact that $1$ is not the successor of any number.